# Sending a FILE pointer to a function for reading

Tags: c

I've been working on this thing for hours on end and I have searched and searched and my code still does not work right.

How do I read my FILE from a function within main using `argv[]` as the file that I want read?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


FILE words(FILE *filesToRead)
{
    const char *Open;
    Open = (char *)filesToRead;

    filesToRead = fopen(Open, "rt");
    int line;
    while ((line = fgetc(filesToRead)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", line);
    }

    fclose(filesToRead);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ah = argv[];
    words(ah);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
void words(char *filename)
{
    FILE *filesToRead = fopen(filename, "rt");
    /* ... */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
        words(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

To be honest (and please don't be offended) the way your code looks it seems you have skipped a few chapters in the C book you are using.

Comment: Yeah, I can`t seem to finish a book for nothing though. I learn best by doing.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[]` is an array of `char *`s. For example, if you call your program from the command line as:

my_prog.exe foo bar

Then:

- `argc` will be 3;
- `argv[0]` will point to "my_prog.exe"
- `argv[1]` will point to "foo"
- `argv[2]` will point to "bar"

So inside your `main()` function, if you are expecting one argument you will need to check the value of `argc` is 2 and then read your argument out of `argv[1]`.

Comment: hmm.. Ok. Still getting errors saying that struct FILE * but argument is type char *

Comment: Your words() function is wrong, too. You'll need @cnicutar's answer for that, I was just trying to help you understand how `argv[]` works.